# copying some nodes from an existing linked list to a new linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to copy some nodes (under certain condition) with my structs looking below.

```
struct node {
    int val;
    int height;
    node *next;
    node *down;
};

struct leapList {
    int height;
    node *head;
};
```

and have my function looking like

```
struct leapList *insertNodeToNextLv(leapList *ogList, leapList *newList) {

    node *head = malloc(sizeof(node *));
    node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node *));
    node *current = malloc(sizeof(node *));

    while(ogList->head != NULL) {
        newnode->val = ogList->head->val;
        if(newList->head == NULL) {
            newnode->next = newList->head;
            newList->head = newnode;
        } else {
            current = newList->head;
            while(current->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            newnode->next = current->next;
            current->next = newnode;
        }
        ogList->head = ogList->head->next;
    }

    
 
   return newList;
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is, I'm trying to pass an already existing singly linked list and a newly made linked list (both in different function malloced). But something doens't seem to be working. When I try to print the original list, it prints as how I want.

I'm trying to iterate through each node in the original list, check if its not NULL (it shouldn't be) and then do the regular create new node and add it to the empty new linked list. But assign the value from the node in the original linked list to the new node I'm trying to add. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to *copy* or to *move* the nodes to the new list? What you seem to be doing now is moving them, not copying them (as that would include creating new nodes).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was tryna copy, also I forgot some lines so I added them back in the question!

Comment: `sizeof(node *)`? That allocates space for a *pointer* to a `node` structure, not space for a `node` structure itself (which would be `sizeof(node)`). Instead of e.g. `node *head = malloc(sizeof(node *))` do `node *head = malloc(sizeof *head)`.

Comment: On another note, do you have a simple function to just add a new node from the `height` and `val` variables? Like `addHead(leapList **list, int val, int height)`? If you don't have such a function I recommend you create it. Because then your `insertNodeToNextLv` function would simply iterate over `ogList` from beginning to end (which is simple) and when it finds a node it should copy it calls the `addHead` function with the new list.

Comment: Another part of your problem: `ogList->head = ogList->head->next;` This will modify the original list, and ultimate leave it empty.

Comment: Also without seeing how `newlist` was initialized, we have no way to know if `newnode->next = newList->head;` works or not.. Do you have a MRE to share? See [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)